# ElasticSearch & Tire: Using Mapping and to_indexed_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

While reading the [*Tire*](http://github.com/karmi/tire) doc, I was under the impression that you should use either `mapping` or `to_indexed_json` methods, since (my understanding was..) the `mapping` is used to feed the `to_indexed_json`.

The problem is, that I found some tutorials where both are used. WHY?

Basically, my app works right now with the `to_indexed_json` but I can't figure out how to set the boost value of some of the attributes (hence the reason I started looking at mapping) and I was wondering if using both would create some conflicts.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

While the `mapping` and `to_indexed_json` methods are related, they serve two different purposes, in fact.

The purpose of the **`mapping`** method is to define *mapping* for the document properties within an index. You may want to define certain property as "not_analyzed", so it is not broken into *tokens*, or set a specific analyzer for the property, or (as you mention) indexing time *boost* factor. You may also define *multifield* property, custom formats for *date* types, etc.

This *mapping* is then used eg. when *Tire* automatically [creates an index for your model](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/lib/tire/model/indexing.rb#L108).

The purpose of the **`to_indexed_json`** method is to define a *JSON serialization* for your documents/models.

The [default `to_indexed_json` method](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/lib/tire/model/search.rb#L159-180) does use your mapping definition, to use only properties defined in the mapping — on a basis that if you care enough to define the *mapping*, by default *Tire* indexes only properties with defined mapping.

Now, when you want a tight grip on how your model is in fact serialized into JSON for *elasticsearch*, you just define your own `to_indexed_json` methods (as the README instructs).

This custom `MyModel#to_indexed_method` usually does not care about *mapping* definition, and builds the JSON serialization from scratch (by leveraging ActiveRecord's `to_json`, using a JSON builder such as [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/), or just building a plain old *Hash* and calling `Hash#to_json`).

So, to answer the last part of your question, using both `mapping` and `to_indexed_json` will absolutely *not* create any conflicts, and is in fact required to use advanced features in elasticsearch.

To sum up:

1. You use the `mapping` method to define the mapping for your models for the search engine
2. You use a custom `to_indexed_json` method to define how the search engine sees your documents/models.

Comment: what if I want to have 2 different index for a single Model. How do I define both indices?

Comment: You cannot have two separate indices for a single model presently in Tire.

Comment: Thanks that's very clear. And so the result of the `to_indexed_json` method is supposed to be in the `_source` element of the search results ?