# How to implement full text search using Elasticsearch in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am following this [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/full-text-search-rails-elasticsearch/) to implement full text search using Elasticsearch in my Rails application but I am getting this error

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

app/models/article.rb: 
   require 'elasticsearch/model' 
     class Article < ActiveRecord::Base 
      include Elasticsearch::Model 
      include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks 
     end 
    Article.import # for auto sync model with elastic search
```

Whenever, I write `Article.import` in my `article.rb` model.

Comment: replace your link with minimal reproducable example so that we can actually see what's going on.

Comment: app/models/article.rb:                                                                                                                         require 'elasticsearch/model'
 
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
end
Article.import # for auto sync model with elastic search

Comment: @awsmsid please update your question with the information you provided in the comments

Comment: Also the error you are getting is probably due to infinite recursion, please paste your indexes in the question as well

Answer (score 0):

Try define method `to_indexed_json`, which tell ES how your JSON serialisation model is.

take a look at this question, [elasticsearch mapping and to_indexed_json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672072/elasticsearch-tire-using-mapping-and-to-indexed-json) , of which the answer clarify what mapping and indexed_json are.

Comment: can anyone tell me how to implement autocomplete word suggestion in my rails app. i am using 'tire' gem as in railscasts episode 307.